# How to assign a specific TAction to a custom control?

Tags: delphi, action

Using Delphi 10.4.1 Sydney.

Starting with a custom component based on `TDBMemo`, I am trying to create a popup menu attached to it that will link to standard actions.
Just not sure how to go about it.

I have this code that creates a PopupMenu for the custom component, and I just want to assign specific actions to the menu items:

```
  PopupItm := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu);
  PopupItm.Caption := '&Undo';
  PopupItm.Name := 'miUndo';
  PopupItm.ShortCut := TextToShortCut('Ctrl+U');
  PopupItm.Action := ???? (want to assign the acUndo from standard action list here
  fPopupMenu.Items.Add(PopupItm);
```

Comment: Do you have a standard `TAction` object created?  You have to populate a `TActionList` with actions, or create the `TAction` objects directly, before you can use them elsewhere.  In this case, [`TEditUndo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdActns.TEditUndo), eg `PopupItm.Action := EditUndo1;` where `EditUndo1` is a `TEditUndo` object.

Comment: Nope.  guess that's where I need to start.
I can add an action list to the component, but how do I add basic, standard actions to it?  do I have to code the actions?

Comment: you don't need an ActionList in your component to use Actions in your component code. Just create the Action objects directly as needed, ie `EditUndo1 := TEditUndo.Create(Self)`.